# How to configure javafx StackedBarChart most "naked"

Tags: javafx, bar-chart

I want to fill javafx GridPane (13x13) with StackedBarChart, but configure it to be most simple: no digits, no labels, no axis, no grids - just single **stackedbar**

Dimentions of cells will be 35x30 pxls

it must look like near (ignore text) :

[image]

Is it possible to reduse sizes of StackedBarChart?
Is it right way to use so many (169) StackedBarChart within GridPane?

Comment: I would use rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

As brian mentioned you can use rectangles to fill your cells. If you want to use a StackedBarChart you can try it with this:

```
yourStackedBarChart.setPrefWidth(yourPixelWidth)
yourStackedBarChart.setPrefHeightyourPixelHeight)
```

Comment: I have fixed it with : stackPane -> {hbox -> resizable % imgs} -> label